# Why can C++ deduce template arguments on the right side of an assignment operator from the left side?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer

```
template <typename T>
void func(T&){
}

int main(){
    void (*p)(int&) = func;//or &func
    return 0;
}
```

I wonder why this code compiles (with g++). It seems the argument of template function is deduced from the type of p? Is this standard behavior?

Edit:
I came up with a possible explanation. That assignment has signature:

```
void(*&)(int&)operator=(void(*)(int&));
```

So func is actually deduced from the input argument type of operator=, rather than from type of *p* directly. Is that correct?

Comment: Note that in the first snippet you posted there is no assignment operator. The `=` occurring in the initialization of a variable does not call `operator =`. E.g. `C x = 4;` would call a constructor of class `C`, not `C::operator=`.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> Is this standard behavior?

Yes it is. Template argument deduction also happens when you take the address of a function template (such as you do when assigning to or initializing a function pointer). It's explicitly allowed in [[temp.deduct.funcaddr]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.deduct.funcaddr):

> Template arguments can be deduced from the type specified when taking
>   the address of an overloaded function. The function template's
>   function type and the specified type are used as the types of P and A,
>   and the deduction is done as described in [temp.deduct.type].

The function pointer type provides the argument (`A` in the above paragraph).

> So func is actually deduced from the input argument type of operator=, rather than from type of p directly. Is that correct?

Not really. For one, it's not assignment, it's initialization that you are doing. And even if it was using an overloaded `operator=` function, you'd need deduction to initialize the argument for the assignment operator, which brings you back to square one.

Comment: The mods are out there. Waiting for the knock on the door.

Comment: Oh, so quick to get an answer. I never thought type can be deduced from left side of assignment before today. Thanks!

Comment: @lowsfer - Easy there. Your example doesn't do assignment, it does initialization. Though the answer would remain the same for assignment as well.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this is a rare case where a C++ expression does not have a specific type until it is used. This is allowed by special-casing detailed [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overloaded_address).

Comment: @Quentin could you elaborate please? You caught my attention.

Comment: @YSC most expressions in C++ have a type. The name of an overloaded function can exist as an expression, but has no type until you resolve the overload, and this is done "from the outside", which is an interesting quirk (and a PITA in generic programming since overload sets are not first-class citizens). Other weird expressions are hidden here and there but are less likely to jump at you, such as [the `foo.bar` in `foo.bar(42);`](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.ref#4.3.2) (it's a prvalue!). There's also initializer lists (the syntax, not the object). It's all mostly useless oddities to be fair :)

Comment: @Quentin ho yes indeed. I didn't know about `[expr.ref]/4.3.2` though. Thx.

Comment: @Quentin - Useless oddities like the most vexing parse? ;)

Comment: @StoryTeller: isn't that the best meaning of "useless"? :)